# openssl EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key() is incompatible with EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key()

Tags: c, openssl, key, ed25519

```
EVP_PKEY_CTX *openssl_ctx = NULL;
openssl_ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_ED25519, NULL);
if (NULL == openssl_ctx)
{
    printf("New Key fail...\n");
    goto cleanup;
}
if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(openssl_ctx)<=0)
{
    printf("EVP_PKEY_keygen_init fail\n");
    goto cleanup;
}
if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(openssl_ctx, ppKey)<=0)
{
    printf("EVP_PKEY_kengen fail\n");
    goto cleanup;
}

ret = ERR_OK;

unsigned char sk[2048], pk[2048];[enter image description here][1]
size_t skLen, pkLen;
if (1 != EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key(*ppKey, pk, &pkLen))
{
    printf("EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key fail");
    char *errStr;
    int line;
    unsigned long err = ERR_get_error_line((const char **)&errStr, &line);
    printf("show me the error: %lu, %s:%i\n", err, errStr, line);
}

int p = EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key(*ppKey, sk, &skLen);
if (p != 1)
{
    printf("EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key fail\n");
    char *errStr;
    int line;
    unsigned long err = ERR_get_error_line((const char **)&errStr, &line);
    printf("show me the error: %lu, %s:%i\n", err, errStr, line);
}
```

I want to export the private key and public key of ed25519 from EVP_PKEY, when I use both  EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key() and EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key(), it returns error:
EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key failshow me the error: 101494966, ../crypto/evp/p_lib.c:310

But when I just use EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key() or EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key(), it reports no error.  Is EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key() incompatible with EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key()?

Answer (score 1):

From the man page for `EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key()`:

> int EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key(const EVP_PKEY *pkey, unsigned char *pub,
> size_t *len);
>
> EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key() fills the buffer provided by pub with raw
> public key data. The size of the pub buffer should be in *len on entry
> to the function, and on exit *len is updated with the number of bytes
> actually written. If the buffer pub is NULL then *len is populated with
> the number of bytes required to hold the key. The calling application is
> responsible for ensuring that the buffer is large enough to receive the public
> key data.

Note the entry conditions: "The size of the pub buffer should be in *len on entry to the function". You are sending an uninitialised value so it may or may not work.

The wording on the man page is similar for `EVP_PKEY_get_raw_private_key`.

Make sure your `skLen` and `pkLen` variables are initialised to the size of the buffer before calling these functions.